# Matplotlib.pyplot.annotate() syntax error

Tags: python, matplotlib

Trying to run this

```
t = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01) 
s = np.cos(2*np.pi*t) 
line, = plt.plot(t, s, lw=2) 
plt.annotate('local max', xy=(2, 1), xytext=(3, 1.5),shrink=0.05),arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', )
plt.ylim(-2,2) 
plt.show()
```

But got the following error:

```
    plt.annotate('local max', xy=(2, 1), xytext=(3, 1.5),shrink=0.05),arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', )
    ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
```

What's wrong with it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html), `shrink` belongs inside `arrowprops`:

```
plt.annotate('local max', xy=(2, 1), xytext=(3, 1.5),
             arrowprops=dict(shrink=0.05, facecolor='black'))
```